# Regex replace all newline characters with comma

Tags: regex

With regex, how do I replace each newline char (\n) with a comma (,)?

Like this:

```
Demetrius Navarro
Tony Plana
Samuel L. Jackson
```

To:

```
Demetrius Navarro,Tony Plana,Samuel L. Jackson
```

Not in a particular programming lang, just standard regex. Something like this:

```
(.*)
$1
//This just takes the whole string and outputs it as is, I think
```

Comment: If all you want to do is replace one character with another, I suggest you just use a string replace method, not regex.

Comment: Please note that regex has different flavors, so I doubt your "just standard regex" will be enough for you.

Comment: I'm using this in a windows program, not a in programming.

Comment: I could use C# code too but pure regex would be preferable

Comment: @Issun I think the program accepts perl style regex

Comment: Ofko, please note that StackOverflow is for programming questions. You could easily have Googled this, or checked your software's documentation.

Comment: Well I think it is relevant because regex is within realm of programming, and I still didn't find out how to do it with regex only. I opted to use C# which works fine.

Answer (score 41):

To match all newline characters, `/\n/g`. In order to replace them, you need to specify a language. For example, in JavaScript:

```
str.replace(/\n/g, ",");
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9eZS9/)

A simple Google search reveals [how it's done in C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace):

```
Regex.Replace(str, "\n", ",");
```

After reading some of your comments, I searched how to do it in Perl. [This should do it](http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html):

```
s/\n/,/g;
```

Comment: @Xeon06 that's exactly what I did

Comment: It occured to me that I could try C#, so I googled, found the function and tried it and it worked.

Comment: The perl examle didn't work, but thanks for your suggestion which lead me to a solution.

Comment: I see. If any answers helped solve your problem, don't forget to consider marking them as the answer to your question by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
/\n/\,/
```

In Vim: `:%s/\n/\,/g` or with a space after the comma (as it is customary): `:%s/\n/\,\ /g`

Comment: The first thing is "the regex". Windows program ... ? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: This was great! It was no biggie to donwload Vim only for formatting my list :)