# How to split a line-by-line string and convert into JSON in Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, replace, split

I tried to split my response string. It is like

```
" hello
  how are you
  what is your name
  thank you "
```

In each line it is surrounded by tab spaces infront of starting word and seperated by lines. eg: "\t\t\t\t HELLO \n \t\t\t\t\t HOW ARE YOU \n......."
I need to convert this into a json object/array like,

```
{obj: hello, how are you, what is your name, thank you}
```

I tried this but it won't works.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('div.block-cont:has(div.tplfcol):has(div.song)').each(function( index ) {
    var titles = $(this).find('div.song-name > h4').text();
    var text = titles.replace("\n", ",");
    console.log(str);
    var myObj = JSON.parse('{"obj": "'+text+'"}');
    console.log(myObj);
});
```

Please help for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex replace all newline characters with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885498/regex-replace-all-newline-characters-with-comma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any complex `regex` for this. Simply, make use of `split()` and `toString()` functions like this,

```js
var str  = '\t\t\t\t HELLO \n \t\t\t\t\t HOW ARE YOU \n \t\t\t\twhat is your name \n \t\t thank you';
var res = str.split('\n').map(x=>x.trim()).toString();
var obj = {obj:res};
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: it returns output like {obj : hello,,how are you,,what is your name,, thank you} . Because there is empty. Help me to remove that. I tried replace(",,",","); but it won't works.

Comment: What empty? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to do without using JSON.parse

```
var str = ...;
var jsonArr = [];
var lines = str.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  jsonArr.push(lines[i]);
}
```

But you can actually just use "lines", rather than copying the contents of lines to jsonArr