# How to remove carriage return characters (for new lines) from a fixtures .CSV file using Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, e2e-testing

In my Cypress test, I'm importing some data from the website and trying to read data from fixtures CSV file for comparison.

Below is the data of my fixtures/sda_ergebnisstatistik_export/Ergebnisstatistik_5Werkstückträger_Export.csv
[image: Fixtues CSV File]

I want the assertion to pass, while comparing the csv data from downloads folder with csv data from fixtures folder.

Here is my latest code, it reads the csv data in downloads folder and validates it with CSV file data in fixtures folder:
[image: Code Snippet from Visual Studio Code IDE]

```js
const grouplist = [' TYP ', ' PRÜFSTAND ', ' TYP/PRÜFSTAND ', ' PRÜFSTAND/TYP ', ' WERKSTÜCKTRÄGER NUMMER ']
it('Ergebnisstatistik - check export for grouplist - Werkstückträger ', function() {
  cy.log('Export the Werkstückträger Nummer table into EXCEL');
  const dayjs = require('dayjs');

  cy.get('button.icon-btn_statistik').should('be.visible').click();
  cy.contains('div>div.option', grouplist[4]).should('be.visible').click();
  cy.wait(500);
  cy.get('.icon-table').click();
  sdi.waitForTable();
  cy.get('.icon-export-table').click();
  cy.readFile(`${Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')}/Ergebnisstatistik ` +
    dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.csv', 'utf-8',
```

{timeout: 15000}).then((downloadCsv) => {
expect(downloadCsv).to.be.a('string')
cy.readFile(`${Cypress.config('fixturesFolder')}/sda_ergebnisstatistik_export/Ergebnisstatistik_5Werkstückträger_Export.csv`,
'utf-8', {timeout: 15000}).then((fixturesCsv) => {
expect(downloadCsv.trim()).to.eq(fixturesCsv.replace('\r\n', '\n').trim());
});
});
});

But the assertion is failing.
[Test Result from Cypress Test Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYXKD.png)

The string from fixtures file has line breaks/carraige controls ("\r\n") from windows OS, where as the string from downloads->csv file contains ("\n") for new line from Linux/Unix OS. I want to remove carraige return \r from each line in the text(of fixturesCsv). So I used .replace('\r\n','\n'). But it is not working as expected for all the rows. In fact, for the first row, it is getting replaced as expected, but not for the remaining rows. Any help to resolve this issue, would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, [do not post image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Again, please stop removing necessary content from your post.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to make the replace expression global (all instances). The trailing `g` sets options to global.

```js
fixturesCsv.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').trim()
```

Example of the step is here [Regex replace all newline characters with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885523/16997707)